# img src doesn't load image through function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Fist of all, I made a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-almeida-u66mlt?file=/src/App.js

The problem is that the requested image doesn't show when the function gets called and the url is returned.

What I have tried so far and the result:

1. First I added the `getDownloadURL()` inside the `querySnapshot.forEach`
   and pushed the retrieved url to the paths array. It looked like
   this:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       const q = query(collection(db, "gallery"));
       const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
         const path = [];
         querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           getDownloadURL(ref(storage, doc.data().bild)).then((url) {
             path.push(doc.data(), url);
            })
         });
         console.log(path);
         setPaths(path);
       });
       setLoading(false);
       return unsubscribe;
     }, []);
   ```

   Then I mapped over paths but the image didn't show.
2. I created another `useState` and called the function `getURL(src)`
   inside `querySnapshot.forEach()`. Inside the `getURL()` function I updated that
   state with the retrieved url from `getDownloadURL()`. Afterwards I
   added the state to src and it worked.

   But my concern is that, when there is more than one image it fails, I
   haven't tested it yet.
3. I converted the retrieved url form `getDownloadURL` to a string. Like so

   `function getURL(src) {...} return String(url)`
   but that didn't work either.

The `<img />` gets rendered with "alt" Text ,so I think it has something to do with url.

I don't understand the problem in general and I hope somebody can help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split you component into small ones. Let's say Gallery and GalleryImage.

GalleryImage will take `src` and `description` props. Declare a `imageSrc` state variable in this component. Then you can do your call in the useEffect (with `src` in the dependencies array) and then set the `imageSrc` state when the call is complete. Calling `setImageSrc` will trigger a re-render.

Updated sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-fire-f84e95

Comment: Thanks a lot :D is there a reason why it failed to load the url? From my point the code wasn't wrong.

Comment: I think that the composant is not re-rendered after the call is done because state needs to be used in order to re-render. Handling state for many element is quite messy so going for a sub component seems to be the proper way to do.
Just ran into this read about async rendering that is interesting btw : https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/asynchronous-rendering-with-react-c323cda68f41/

Comment: ohhhh I see, that makes sense to me. Thanks! 

Comment: @Jerunnon, Frank's solution is way more efficient, you should go for this one

Answer (score 2):

Both loading data from Firestore, and getting a download URL for an image is an asynchronous operation. You're calling `setPaths(path)` before any of the calls to `path.push(doc.data(), url)` have happened.

I recommend running the code in a debugger, or adding logging, to verify this, as it is key to understanding how to deal with asynchronous APIs.

The solution is always the same: any code that needs data that is loaded asynchronously, needs to be **inside** the callback that gets called when that data is available.

So in your case, the simplest way to do that would be:

```
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  const path = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, doc.data().bild)).then((url) {
      path.push(doc.data(), url);
      setPaths(path); // 
    })
  });
});
```

This sets the paths every time you get a download URL.

---

If you want to wait setting the paths until you got all download URLs, you can use a counter to check the number of documents vs the number of download URLs, or you can use promises and `Promise.all`:

```
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => getDownloadURL(ref(storage, doc.data().bild)))
  Promise.all(promises).then((urls) {
    setPaths(urls);
  })
});
```

Comment: Understood, thanks for the explaination :D